# Hadoop configuration: mapred.* vs mapreduce.*

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I noticed that there are two sets of Hadoop configuration parameters: one with mapred.* and the other with mapreduce.*. I am guessing these might be due to old API vs. new API but if I am not mistaken, these seem to coexist in the new API. Am I correct? If so, is there a generalized statement what is used for mapred.* and what is for mapreduce.*?

Comment: I guess my question was quite ambiguous. I was not asking about libraries. I am asking about two different hadoop configuration parameter namings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining the source for 0.20.2, there are only a few `mapreduce.*` properties, and they revolve around configuring the job input/output format, mapper/combiner/reducer and partitioner classes (they also signal to the job client that the new API is being used by the user - look through the source for `o.a.h.mapreduce.Job`, `setUseNewAPI()` method)

- `mapreduce.inputformat.class`
- `mapreduce.outputformat.class`
- `mapreduce.partitioner.class`
- `mapreduce.map.class`
- `mapreduce.combine.class`
- `mapreduce.reduce.class`

There are some more properties but they are secondary configuration

The input and output formats, whether it be new or old API versions, typically use `mapred.*` properties

For example, the signal your map reduce input paths you use `mapred.input.dir` (whether you're using the new or old API). Same for the output property `mapred.output.dir`

So the long and the short of if is, if there isn't a utility method to configure the property (`FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(Job, String)`) then you'll need to check the source

Answer (score 2):

Yes mapred library has been deprecated. mapreduce library is new in hadoop 0.20.1..

However, you can still use some of the features offered by mapred, which is why you still find it in the directory.

Please have a look at this link to know what features you can still use: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/package-summary.html

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

`hadoop.mapred` has been deprecated.

Versions before `0.20.1` used `mapred`.
Versions after that use `mapreduce`.

I do not think they co-exists.