# How to get compressed (text) output from a streaming Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, compression, mapreduce

I have read and tried every example I could find for what seems like this straight forward problem.  Assume there is a set of uncompressed text files and that I want to run a processing step on them and then output a set of compressed files with the results.  To keep things simple, this example assumes `cat` as the processing step.

Everything I found suggests this should work:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -Dmap.output.compress=true \
    -Dmap.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
    -mapper /bin/cat \
    -reducer NONE \
    -input /path_to_uncompressed \
    -output /path_to_compressed
```

The job runs normally, but outputs plain text files.  I have tried varying the input file sizes, varying the codec (Snappy, BZip2, etc.), adding a reducer, setting mapred.output.compression.type (BLOCK, RECROD), etc. and the result is always the same.  For reference, I am using a new install of CDH 4.1.2.

Answer (score 7):

The followings work on Hadoop *v1.0.0* :

This will produce a gzipped output:

```
hadoop jar /home/user/hadoop/path_to_jar/hadoop-streaming-1.0.0.jar \
    -D mapred.output.compress=true \
    -D mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
    -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
    -mapper /bin/cat \
    -input /user/hadoop/test/input/test.txt \
    -output /user/hadoop/test/output
```

A block-compressed SequenceFile as output:

```
hadoop jar /home/user/hadoop/path_to_jar/hadoop-streaming-1.0.0.jar \
    -D mapred.output.compress=true \
    -D mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK \
    -D mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
    -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
    -mapper /bin/cat \
    -input /user/hadoop/test/input/test.txt \
    -output /user/hadoop/test/output
    -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat
```

Note the order of the parameters as well as the **space** between -D and the property name.

In case of YARN many properties have been deprecated (see the complete list [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.1.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html)) . Therefore you have to do the following changes:

**mapred.output.compress -> mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
mapred.output.compression.codec -> mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec
mapred.output.compression.type -> mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type**

Comment: Tried both commands exactly on my Cloudera distro (4.1.2 -> Hadoop 2.0.0) and they do **not** work.  I tried on a separate 1.0.3 installation I have and they both worked fine.  Either something has changed in 2.0.0 or something is broken in this version/distro.  Not finding any other reports of issues with CDH4 and compression and not sure what to try next.  The verbose option wasn't much help other than to confirm the properties got defined as expected.  Maybe I need to try lowering the log level to debug and see if anything shows up there?

Comment: I am using the v1 MapReduce in CDH4 so almost certain the original properties were the right ones.  Among other things, the Cloudera Manager referring to the mapred.* versions in its Compression configuration section.  Luckily this did at lead me to a solution of sorts.  They have a "client override" setting for mapred.output.compress.  If I set this to true then everything starts to work, albeit without job-level control of that setting.  I do still have job-level control of the codec, however.  Oh well, this is good enough for me right now - something definitely wrong though I think.

Comment: So did you manage to fix this issue? Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: There are two versions of the options: *mapred* and *mapreduce*. Be sure to try both to see which works with your hadoop version. See this question for more clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986633/hadoop-configuration-mapred-vs-mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudera Manager, 
go to
Services > Service mapreduce > Configuration > TaskTracker > Compression

- Compress MapReduce Job Output (Client Override) : Don't override client configuration

Answer (score -2):

I work for Cloudera and came across this post.  I just wanted to let you know that Cloudera Manager 4.5 (the version I confirmed) at least, has the option to NOT override the client config in addition to overriding the client config to true or to false.  This makes it ideal as you can change that setting to allow the developer to choose whether or not to compress output.  Hope that helps--I know this is a while ago now. :)

Comment: can you please add in some relevant links and maybe code snippets showing how to do that so it reads less like an ad. Thanks.